# Round two decimals in CG shader in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

Is there any way how to round down float to two decimal places? I googled everywhere but without success. I found only round() function, but it is rounding to integer, but I need round number like 0.168354985 to 0.17

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there some CG specific method for that, but in general you can do something like this

```
round(value * 100) / 100;
```